# Random MAC address each time at startup

Tags: linux, debian, privacy

I would like to get a random MAC address every time I turn on my Linux machine (Debian). Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: It's possible, but it provides no meaningful privacy at all. You can go to a restaurant in a different disguise under a different name every day and fool absolutely no one. Random MACs are about the same level of effective; don't bother.

Comment: @msw :  Seems to me that would depend on context.  For example, if you are *literally* walking into the same restaurant everyday and using the free wifi, spoofing your MAC address does provide privacy.  It is the only way that your day after day presence could be logged, or recognized.

Comment: NOTICE: This question has been crossposted to another SE group!  
This is very bad practice.

Comment: @goldilocks there is a whole domain of "traffic analysis" which suggests exactly the opposite. Keeping to my silly example, if anyone was watching and cared, being the guy in the restaurant with the random MAC every day would identify you as surely as does the "hand" of a telegraph operator. And although you would be spoofing the data-link layer, being the guy who downloads  pictures of calico kittens each time he enters would mark you far more vividly than anything else ("Don't know who he is, but he sure likes his calicos").

Comment: @mdpc which other SE site did you see this? The OP has only an account on Unix/Linux

Comment: @Anthon: Though different user, this looks like a rather safe bet: http://askubuntu.com/q/336472/101774 (timestamp taken into account). But, can of course also be the result of a chat, pure chance, an RSS feed triggering questions in two readers etc … :)

Comment: @Sukminder Thanks I googled but did not see that one, same long-time-no-see on the poster as well

Answer (score 9):

It is possible, look at [How to change MAC address](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/09/how-to-change-mac-address-of-your.html), posted at September 14, 2005 by Ravi.

Changing MAC address of a machine is called spoofing a MAC address or faking a MAC address. In linux, you can change MAC address of your machine.This is how it is done.

#### How to change MAC address in Linux

First find the physical MAC address of your machine by running the following command:

```
$ ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:80:48:BA:d1:20
```

The hexadecimal numbers in blue denote my machine's MAC address. Yours will be different. Learn how to use the ifconfig Linux command.

You can also use ethtool to find the hardware address of your machine.

Next, login as root in Linux and enter the following commands:

```
# ifconfig eth0 down
# ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:80:48:BA:d1:30
# ifconfig eth0 up
# ifconfig eth0 |grep HWaddr
```

I have changed the MAC address to a different number highlighted in blue. 00:80:48:BA:d1:30 is the new MAC address I have provided for my Linux machine. You can choose any 48 bits hexadecimal address as your MAC address.

#### Why you should change MAC address of your Linux machine

These are the reasons you should change the MAC address of your machine.

- For privacy  - For instance when you are connecting to a Wi-Fi hotspot.
- To ensure interoperability. Some internet service providers bind their service to a specific MAC address; if the user then changes their network card or intends to install a router, the service won't work anymore. Changing the MAC address of the new interface will solve the problem.

#### Caveats to Changing MAC address

In Linux, Windows, Mac OS X, or a different operating system, changing MAC address is only temporary. Once you reboot your machine, the operating system reflects the physical MAC address burnt in your network card and not the MAC address you set.

Still if you are looking for privacy as @msw pointed out I would go the [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) way.

Comment: +1 for answering the weak question. Added caveat: being the "guy who uses TOR" would mark you in traffic analysis far more clearly than any MAC ever could. Put another way: even if I brought in a different real device every day but had the same habits, I'd fool no one who cared.

Comment: I also got creative and worked out a random mac generator: `dd if=/dev/random bs=2 count=3 2>/dev/null | perl -e '$hex = <>; $hex = unpack("H*", $hex) ; $hex =~ s/(..)(?!.?$)/$1:/g; print "$hex\n";'`

Comment: @msw so which are the alternatives? Using an open proxy? I`ve used a reverse proxy to circunvent firewalls but I'm aware they can see me.

Comment: Alternatives are strictly dependent upon what you're trying to hide from. If, for example, you've got a government agency which is very interested in your activities, the answer is usually "nothing". Of course there are lesser degrees of interest, but I know that a forged MAC protects you against only distracted 6-year-old kids and similarly uninterested parties. In between those poles I truly have no idea of what's effective and not.

Comment: @DravSloan this is great, but note that it works only half the time, because the [first byte should be even](http://askubuntu.com/a/536221/125111). Ideally it would even be 2 mod 4, so that it is locally administered.